# Interaction Lagrangian forms

Tags: classical-electrodynamics

When a charge motion is given (known), the electromagnetic field can be explicitly found (Retarded potentials, etc.). The interaction Lagrangian density is $j\cdot A$ or in the action it may look like $\int A_{\mu}dx^{\mu}=\int A_{\mu}\dot{x}^{\mu}dt$.

My question is: can the latter be transformed into something like $\int F_{\mu\nu}\dot{x}^{\mu}x^{\nu}dt$ with integrating by parts and using the fact that the charge position and its velocity are given functions of time?

Comment: In case of a constant magnetic field $B$, the vector potential can be expressed as $A=(1/2)B×x$. It may be that more is possible in terms of the Power-Zienau-Woolley transformation. See C. Cohen-Tannoudji, J. Dupont-Roc and G. Grynberg, Atom-Photon Interactions (Wiley, New York, 1998).

Comment: Yes, and in case of a constant electric field it can be $\varphi=-\bf{r}\cdot\bf{E}$, but I am interested in a time-dependent field sourced with a charge motion.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one suggestion: Assuming that spacetime is [star-shaped](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_domain) around the origin $x=0$, define the interaction Lagrangian as

$$L_{\rm int}(\tau)~:=~ x^{\mu}(\tau)~ \dot{x}^{\nu}(\tau)\int_0^1\! d\alpha~\alpha~  F_{\mu\nu}(\alpha x(\tau))  $$
$$ ~=~ \int_0^1\! d\alpha~\alpha~ x^{\mu}(\tau)~ \partial_{\mu}A_{\nu}(\alpha x(\tau))~ \dot{x}^{\nu}(\tau) 
-\int_0^1\! d\alpha~\alpha~ \dot{x}^{\nu}(\tau)~ \partial_{\nu}A_{\mu}(\alpha x(\tau))~x^{\mu}(\tau) $$
$$ ~=~ \int_0^1\! d\alpha~\alpha~ \frac{dA_{\nu}(\alpha x(\tau))}{d\alpha}~ \dot{x}^{\nu}(\tau) 
-\int_0^1\! d\alpha~\frac{dA_{\mu}(\alpha x(\tau))}{d\tau}~x^{\mu}(\tau) $$
$$ ~\sim~ \left[\alpha~ A_{\nu}(\alpha x(\tau))~ \dot{x}^{\nu}(\tau) \right]_{\alpha=0}^{\alpha=1}-\int_0^1\! d\alpha~A_{\nu}(\alpha x(\tau))~ \dot{x}^{\nu}(\tau) +\int_0^1\! d\alpha~ A_{\mu}(\alpha x(\tau))~\dot{x}^{\mu}(\tau) $$
$$~=~ A_{\nu}( x(\tau))~ \dot{x}^{\nu}(\tau).$$

Here the $\sim$ symbol means equality modulo total $\frac{d}{d\tau}$ derivative terms.